# text vectorizer using sckitlearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

i am using sckit-learn to do preprocessing on text data my aim is to get vector representation of my data (features and label) , what i have done is vectorizing the feature using tfidf after that the dataset size changed by double size as **X.ravel()** is used .

X before (30376, 2)

X after (60752, 41331)

my problem is that when i am having two features in the x vector and i want to get vector representation correctly how i can do it

```
 df = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv',encoding='latin1')
    df = df.dropna()



    X = np.array(df.drop(['Type'], 1))
    y = np.array(df['Type'])




    #print(X)

    print("Extracting features from the training data using a sparse vectorizer")
    vectorizer= TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,
                                     stop_words='english')
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X.ravel().astype('U'))

    imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
    X = imp.fit_transform(X)
    X.shape
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

and if that the case when i am using **train_test_split** i get this error i don't understand what it referring to

```
TypeError: Singleton array array(TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.int64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=0.5, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), norm='l2', preprocessor=None, smooth_idf=True,
        stop_words='english', strip_accents=None, sublinear_tf=True,
        token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b', tokenizer=None, use_idf=True,
        vocabulary=None), dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

any suggestion and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either `X` or `y` has a wrong shape.

Here is an [excerpt from the validation.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L118) which is used for validating passed data sets:

```
if hasattr(x, 'shape'):
    if len(x.shape) == 0:  # <----- NOTE !!!
        raise TypeError("Singleton array %r cannot be considered"
                        " a valid collection." % x)
    return x.shape[0]
else:
    return len(x)
```

Comment: the problem here is that  X has two feature but appears that TfidfVectorizer combine the two features to be one array with double size
X before (30376, 2)
X after (60752, 41331)

Comment: @ahmedosama, don't try to ask too many questions within one question on SO. If I understood your original question correctly - you asked: " i don't understand what the error '...' is referring to". I have answered that question. If you have another/new question please open (ask) a new question, specify there related code and provide a small reproducible data set so people from SO community could easily reproduce it and find a solution

Comment: sorry , edited the main question . please let me know if it still vague